# C# day of week date ranges repetition pattern

Tags: .net, linq, c#-4.0, lambda

I am developing an agenda and I have this method that brings me dates that occur in a given period on selected days of the week. This works well .

Now my problem:
I'm trying to implement an option to choose the pattern of repetition.

For example, **every 2 weeks.**

so I need a way to not include dates that do not fit.

For example:

```
    // example dates
    string strStart = "2014-03-17";
    string strEnd = "2014-04-14";

    DateTime start, end;

    DateTime.TryParse(strStart, out start);
    DateTime.TryParse(strEnd, out end);

    // example days of week
    List<DayOfWeek> dw = new List<DayOfWeek>();
    dw.Add(DayOfWeek.Monday);
    dw.Add(DayOfWeek.Tuesday);

    Dates = GetDayofWeekDateOcurrences(start, end, dw, 2);
```

This give this list of dates;

```
// result
/*
    > 2014-03-17
    > 2014-03-18
    > 2014-03-24
    > 2014-03-25
    > 2014-03-31
    > 2014-04-01
    > 2014-04-07
    > 2014-04-08
    > 2014-04-14
*/



// desired dates for a two week repetition
/*
    > 2014-03-17 // monday
    > 2014-03-18 // tuesday

    > 2014-04-07 // monday
    > 2014-04-08  // tuesday

*/
```

Method;

```
private List<DateTime> GetDayofWeekDateOcurrences(DateTime start, DateTime end, List<DayOfWeek> dw, int repeatOn)
{

   // repeatOn Will be for example : every 2 weeks;

    int numberOfDays = end.Subtract(start).Days + 1;

    var dates = Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfDays)
                          .Select(i => start.AddDays(i)) // (i * repeatOn)  gives wrong dates
                          .Where(d => dw.Contains(d.DayOfWeek) && d <= end).ToList();


    return dates.ToList();

}
```

Comment: Sorry if I could not be more clear. I edited the question hoping to have expressed myself better.

Comment: Your code works correctly (I just try). What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The code works for a list of dates in the range start and End for monday and thusday. The problem is that i want to only include dates that fall on a 2 weeks repeticion. comment ( desired dates for a two week repetition) Thanks

Comment: I'm confused... You're desired dates are three weeks apart whereas I expected two weeks. There are also other pairs of dates that are two weeks apart in that range (in fact all of the dates are two weeks apart from at least one other date)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work if you want to use LINQ:

```
private List<DateTime> GetDayofWeekDateOcurrences(DateTime start, DateTime end, int everyNthWeek, List<DayOfWeek> dw)
{
    int numberOfDays = end.Subtract(start).Days + 1;

    var dates = Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfDays)
        .GroupBy(i => i / 7 % everyNthWeek)
        .Where(g => g.Key == 0)
        .SelectMany(g => g.Select(i => start.AddDays(i))
                          .Where(d => dw.Contains(d.DayOfWeek)))
        .ToList();

    return dates;
}
```